# pandas resample: forcing specific start time of time bars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I have some time series `data` (`pandas.DataFrame`) and I resample it in `'600S'` bars:

```py
import numpy as np
data.resample('600S', level='time').aggregate({'abc':np.sum})
```

I get something like this:

```
                   abc
time                
09:30:01.446000  19836
09:40:01.446000   8577
09:50:01.446000  29746
10:00:01.446000  29340
10:10:01.446000   5197
...
```

How can I force the time bars to start at `09:30:00.000000` instead of at the time of the 1st row in the data? I.e. output should be something like this:

```
                   abc
time                
09:30:00.000000  *****
09:40:00.000000   ****
09:50:00.000000  *****
10:00:00.000000  *****
10:10:00.000000   ****
...
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.resample` is a bit of a wildcard. It behaves rather differently with `datetime64[ns]` and `timedelta64[ns]` so I personally find it more reliable to work with `groupby`, when just doing things like `.sum` or `.first`.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 1000
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.date_range('2018-01-01 01:13:43', '2018-01-01 23:59:59', periods=n),
                   'abc': np.random.randint(1,1000,n)})
```

When the `dtype` is `datetime64[ns]` it will resample to "round" bins:

```
df.dtypes
#time    datetime64[ns]
#abc              int32
#dtype: object

df.set_index('time').resample('600S').sum()
                      abc
time                     
2018-01-01 01:10:00  2572
2018-01-01 01:20:00  2257
2018-01-01 01:30:00  2470
2018-01-01 01:40:00  3131
2018-01-01 01:50:00  3402
```

With `timedelta64[ns]` it instead begins the bins based on your first observation:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.time.dt.time.astype('str'))
df.dtypes
#time    timedelta64[ns]
#abc               int32
#dtype: object

df.set_index('time').resample('600S').sum()
           abc
time          
01:13:43  3432
01:23:43  2447
01:33:43  2588
01:43:43  3202
01:53:43  2547
```

So in the case of a `timedelta64[ns]` column, I'd advise you to go with `groupby` creating bins out of `.dt.floor` to create your 10 minute bins that go from `[XX:00:00 - XX:10:00]`

```
df.groupby(df.time.dt.floor('600S')).sum()
#           abc
#time          
#01:10:00  2572
#01:20:00  2257
#01:30:00  2470
#01:40:00  3131
#01:50:00  3402
```

This is the same result we got in the first case with the `datetime64[ns]` dtype, which binned to the "round" bins.

Answer (score 4):

You can add [`Series.dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) to your code:

```
df.time = df.time.dt.floor('10 min')

              time    abc
0 2018-12-05 09:30:00  19836
1 2018-12-05 09:40:00   8577
2 2018-12-05 09:50:00  29746
3 2018-12-05 10:00:00  29340
4 2018-12-05 10:10:00   5197
```

Comment: rounding will not work , for example , 09:30:01 and 09:40:02, used to belong to two different group , right now it be come one group,

Comment: Agree with W-B. You'd need to use that in a `groupby` instead of resample: `df.groupby(df.time.dt.floor('10min')).abc.sum()`

Comment: Yes agreed, however the idea would be to add this after the `resample` and `aggregation` already done

Comment: It works if applied on the original data before resampling is done and using groupby instead of resample (as @ALollz proposed).

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is robust to it and you want to *extend* the time *before* the actual starting time, a solution is to add an empty row at the starting time you want.

E.g. truncating the first time (`df.loc[0]` if the index is sorted, else `df.index.min()`) to its hour (`.floor("h")`) :

```
df.loc[df.index.min().floor("h")] = None
df.sort_index(inplace=True) # cleaner, but not even needed
```

Then `resample()` will use this time as the starting point (`9:00` in OP’s case).

This can also be applied to extend the time range *after* the actual end of the dataset.